# Two variables with inconsistent names as input for a Snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

How can I pair up input data for rules in snakemake if the naming isn't consistent and they are all in the same folder?
For example if I want to use each pair of samples as input for each rule:

- PT1 T5
- S6    T7
- S1    T20

In this example I would want to have 3 pairs PT1 & T5, S6 & T7, S1 & T20 so to start with, I would want to create 3 folders:

- PT1vsT5
- S6vsT7
- S1vsT20

And then perform an analysis with manta and output the results into these 3 folders accordingly.

In the following pipeline I want the GERMLINE sample to be the first element in each line (PT1, S6, S1) and TUMOR the second one (T5, T7, T20).

```
rule all:
 input:
      expand("/{samples_g}vs{samples_t}", samples_g = GERMLINE, samples_t = TUMOR),
      expand("/{samples_g}vs{samples_t}/runWorkflow.py", samples_g = GERMLINE, samples_t = TUMOR),

# Create folders
rule folders:
  output: "./{samples_g}vs{samples_t}"
  shell: "mkdir {output}"

# Manta configuration
rule manta_config:  
  input:
       g = BAMPATH + "/{samples_g}.bam",
       t = BAMPATH + "/{samples_t}.bam"
  output:
       wf = "{samples_g}vs{samples_t}/runWorkflow.py"
  params:
       ref = IND,
       out_dir = "{samples_g}vs{samples_t}/runWorkflow.py"
  shell:
       "python configManta.py --normalBam {input.g} --tumorBam {input.t} --referenceFasta {params.ref} --runDir {params.out_dir} "
```

Could I do it by using as an input a .txt containing the pairs and then use a loop? If so how should I do it? Otherwise how could it be done?

Comment: To solve problems related to inconsistent file naming, one can create symbolic links to these files, with consistent naming. This can even be done within snakemake, providing the desired correspondence between original file names and link names in the configuration file, for instance.

Comment: In your case, you can perhaps just use `zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)` to "manually" create the list of files, instead of using `expand`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the list of input or output files "manually" using any appropriate python code. For instance, you could proceed as follows to generate the first of your input lists:

```python
In [1]: GERMLINE = ("PT1", "S6", "S1")

In [2]: TUMOR = ("T5", "T7", "T20")

In [3]: ["/{}vs{}".format(sample_g, sample_t) for (sample_g, sample_t) in zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)]
Out[3]: ['/PT1vsT5', '/S6vsT7', '/S1vsT20']
```

So this would be applied as follows:

```python
rule all:
    input:
        ["/{}vs{}".format(sample_g, sample_t) for (sample_g, sample_t) in zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)],
        ["/{}vs{}/runWorkflow.py".format(sample_g, sample_t) for (sample_g, sample_t) in zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)],
```

(Note that I put `sample_g` and `sample_t` in singular form, as it sounded more logical in this context, where those variable represent individual sample names, and not lists of several samples)

Comment: Thanks for your help!